# Output raw special characters in XML from PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, special-characters

I am editing a config file using PowerShell. I need to output the following exactly like this: "<FieldDelimiter>&#9;</FieldDelimiter>". It, of course, wants to translate the tab character and write a tab (white space).  The closest I've gotten is for it to output: "<FieldDelimiter>&amp;#9;</FieldDelimiter>", which is no good.  How can I get it to write to the file the ampersand itself?

I'm reading in the file:

```
[xml]$xml = (Get-Content $configFilePath)  
...(skip some code)...
```

appending some child elements:

```
$configuration = $xml.CreateElement("Configuration")
$newExtension = $xml.CreateElement("Extension")

$configuration.InnerXml = "
            <DeviceInfo>
                <FieldDelimiter>&#9;</FieldDelimiter>
                <UseFormattedValues>True</UseFormattedValues>
                <NoHeader>True</NoHeader>
                <FileExtension>txt</FileExtension>
            </DeviceInfo>"

$newExtension.AppendChild($configuration)
...(more code skipped)...
$xml.Configuration.Extensions.Render.InsertAfter($newExtension, $csvNode)
```

then saving the file.

```
$xml.Save($configFilePath)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:
I was not able to get an answer on how to output simply an ampersand character in the XML without encoding, and I was running out of time on the project, so here's what I did that worked (not the preferred answer, but it works).

I read the file again and replaced the "&amp;" with "&" like below:

```
$config = (Get-Content $configFilePath)
$newConfig = $config.Replace('&amp;', '&')
Out-File -FilePath $configFilePath -InputObject $newConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the ampersand `&`:

```
<FieldDelimiter>&amp;#9;</FieldDelimiter>
```

As a test, I created this script:

```
$x = [xml]@"
<DeviceInfo>
  <FieldDelimiter>&amp;#9;</FieldDelimiter>
  <UseFormattedValues>True</UseFormattedValues>
  <NoHeader>True</NoHeader>
  <FileExtension>txt</FileExtension>
</DeviceInfo>
"@
$x.Save("c:\temp\testEscape.xml")
```

Then I test reading resulting file:

```
# C:\Temp> gc .\testEscape.xml
<DeviceInfo>
  <FieldDelimiter>&amp;#9;</FieldDelimiter>
  <UseFormattedValues>True</UseFormattedValues>
  <NoHeader>True</NoHeader>
  <FileExtension>txt</FileExtension>
</DeviceInfo>
# C:\Temp> $x = [xml](gc .\testEscape.xml)
# C:\Temp> $x.DeviceInfo.FieldDelimiter
&#9;
```

Comment: The output in the file ends up as described in the original post.  I've tried what you have shown. I've also tried escaping it, which for PowerShell is a backtick "`" character, and that doesn't work.  I've also tried using $#38; and that ends up written to file as mentioned above.

Comment: @AndrewHoltsclaw ok i see, what's not clear to me is why outputting in this format is "no good", if you then query the resulting inner text `&amp;#9;` with an xml parser you will get `&#9;` which is what I presume you want.

Comment: This is an SSRS config file. SSRS will treat &#9; as a tab character, but it will not treat &amp;#9; as a tab character (I've tested it).  I'm not sure if there are other acceptable tab characters besides &#9;, but I know the one there (&amp;#9) is not acceptable. Considering that &#9; is acceptable, it appears to be expecting HTML entities, thus no matter what I output, I will need to figure out how to simply write a single ampersand just like '&', unless someone knows another acceptable tab character for an SSRS config file.